# PHP preg_replace [LINK]mylink[/LINK]

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

Let's have a php `string` like this with [n] links:

```
This is a text with a link to [LINK]https://website.com/page/subpage/id This is the text to display[/LINK] and another link to [LINK]https://website2.com/page/subpage/subsubpage/subsubsubpage This is the text to display for link 2[/LINK]. Wow!"
```

How would I replace the [LINK] and [/LINK] with `a href` and display the text for the link?

Lik this: `<a href="https://website.com/page/subpage/id" target="_blank">This is the text to display</a>`

I have tried `preg_replace` but could not figure it out as it is super weirdo!!

Comment: Try `$updated_string = str_replace('[LINK]',$link,$string);`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$str='This is a text with a link to [LINK]https://website.com This is the text to display[/LINK] and another link to [LINK]https://website2.com This is the text to display for link 2[/LINK]. Wow!';

$pattern='/\[LINK\]([\w:\/\.]+) ([^(\[\/LINK\])]+)\[\/LINK\]/';

echo preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="${1}" target="_blank">${2}</a>', $str) ;

?>
```

output is

```
This is a text with a link to <a href="https://website.com" target="_blank">This is the text to display</a> and another link to <a href="https://website2.com" target="_blank">This is the text to display for link 2</a>. Wow!
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: How would the pattern look like when the hrefs look like `https://www.domain/page/action/item?`

Comment: Anyone who can help?